# Bluetooth AG (source) help for a working simpel example 8675 (not USB)

Tags: bluetooth, csr, adk, qualcomm

i am trying to make a simpel AG for the CSR 8675. In ADK 4.4 i cant get anything to work, but in ADK 4.3.1 it looks like at least the sink works, but all AG, or source as they call them now, are examples made for a USB dongle so it is missing a lot. I did try to compile these and i also did try to add the pairing switch (pio11), but it seems like this AG will do noting without the USB connection, and this is not possible here. I just need some help to make it pair and connect, then i can handle the rest myself.. Anybody have a good guide or example code ?

I did try to play with the settings, change it to analog instead of USB, configure the keys etc, but nothing seems to work here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm afraid your question is too broad/off-topic here. I would recommend that you contact your distributor's FAE or ask Qualcomm.

Comment: have you ever tried to contact qualcomm ? i have used months on them without any success, i wish it was that simple

Comment: Yes, I do it from time to time.

Comment: try ADK 4.1 or something lower (but maybe not lower than ADK3.5) on two official development boards (one with source project other with sink). The sample source project in older ADK should work